# converting react class to functional component with refs

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, react-functional-component

I'm trying to use a class example from a [stackblitz file](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6yxx2s-ws9f9w?file=index.js) and convert it to a functional component.

I don't understand how the ref works, or where the `event` and `args` that are being used in the `onTyping` function are coming from. Can anyone explain where those are defined and how I'd translate this to a functional component?

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns';
import { SampleBase } from './sample-base';

import * as data from './dataSource.json';
export class Default extends SampleBase {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.temp = 'sportsData';
        // define the array of string
        this.sportsData = data[this.temp];
    }
    onTyping(args) {
console.log(event.target.value);
    }
    render() {
        return (<div id='combodefault' className='control-pane'>
        <div className='control-section'>
        <div className='col-lg-12 control-wrappers'>
            <div id='default'>
            <AutoCompleteComponent id="games" dataSource={this.sportsData} ref={(AutoComplete) => { this.listObj = AutoComplete; }} placeholder="e.g. Basketball" actionBegin={this.onTyping}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>);
    }
}

render(<Default />, document.getElementById('sample'));
```

Comment: `this.listObj`, the property assigned in the `ref`, does not appear to be used anywhere. Is that ref needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anything in the constructor will need to be translated to useState:

```
    this.temp = 'sportsData';
    // define the array of string
    this.sportsData = data[this.temp];
```

becomes:

```
const[temp, setTemp] = useState('sportsData');
const[sportsData, setSportsData] = useState(data[temp]);
```

setTemp and setSportsData are functions that you use to set the state variable temp and sportsData respectively. For example, the following will set temp to 'NFSSportsData'.

```
setTemp('NFLSportsData');
```

As for the `ref`, you can use the hook useRef.

```
const listObj = useRef(null);
```

for component life cycle method componentDidMount, you can use the following convention.

```
useEffect(()=>{
// your code
}, [])
```

the empty bracket [] signifies only to run the code once when the component mounts. If you want to code listen to a state variable, and runs every time the variable changes, you can do the following:

```
useEffect(()=>{
// your code
}, [sportsData])
```

This code above will run every time state variable sportsData changes.

I don't think there's a way to extend a functional component like you are doing with SampleBase. Looking at the SampleBase class, it's just running a function in the lifecycle component componentDidMount. You can do something like the following:

```
rendereComplete() {
    /**custom render complete function */
}
useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.rendereComplete();
},[]);
```

To tie is all together, you have something like the following:

```
import './index.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns';
import * as data from './dataSource.json';

export const Default = ()=> {
  const [temp, setTemp] = React.useState('sportsData');
  const [sportsData, setSportsData] = useState(data[this.temp]);
  const listObj = useRef(null);

  const onTyping = (args)=>{
    console.log('arg =', args);
  }
  
  const rendereComplete() {
        /**custom render complete function */
    }
  useEffect(()=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
        rendereComplete();
  },[]);
  return (<div id='combodefault' className='control-pane'>
  <div className='control-section'>
  <div className='col-lg-12 control-wrappers'>
      <div id='default'>
      <AutoCompleteComponent id="games" dataSource={sportsData} ref={(AutoComplete) => { listObj = AutoComplete; }} placeholder="e.g. Basketball" actionBegin={onTyping}/>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>);
}
```